# How to enable "Export Billing" information google cloud using REST API for both Bucket and BigQuery

Tags: c#, .net, rest, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

As per google console, we can use below steps to enable export of billing information over google cloud.

1. If you haven't already created a bucket in Google Cloud Storage, you need to create one. For instructions, see Creating Storage Buckets.
2. Then to enable billing export, go to the Cloud Platform Console.
3. Open the left side menu and select Billing
4. If you have more than one billing account, select Go to linked billing account to manage the current project's billing. To locate a different billing account, select Manage billing accounts.
5. Click Billing export.
6. Select File export.
7. For Bucket name, specify name of the Cloud Storage bucket into which billing reports will be exported. The Google Service Account is granted write access to this bucket.
8. For Report prefix, specify a prefix for the Cloud Storage object name for the exported reports. The year, month, and day is appended to the prefix.
9. For Format, select CSV or JSON
10. Click Enable billing export

But we want achieve same thing using REST API, but we dont have any luck to find that.
Kindly help to find REST API for enabling "Billing Export" for both BigQuery and Bucket over Google Cloud.

Comment: It feels to me like this would be in the Billing API if it were supported, but I can't see any sign of it at https://cloud.google.com/billing/v1/getting-started - which suggests to me that it's not supported at the moment. (Disclaimer: I know about the generated C# client libraries in general, but not the Billing API in particular.)

Comment: Having looked and asked internally, I don't believe it's feasible at the moment.

Comment: Just for understanding purpose, i am asking that if we can't enable these export billing information using API then how to achieve complete automation in term of getting billing data. As we have API to create bucket and get bucket data either in CSV or JSON format but only enabling part is not possible. Please update me how to achieve that.

Comment: I'm afraid I really don't know - it may not be feasible at the moment. Although enabling it would be a one time action per project, presumably.

Comment: Its ok. Thanks for your update and help.

Answer (score 3):

Billing export to BigQuery is now GA, and I still don't see any way to configure it outside of the web interface.

I've submitted a feature request here:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/70525274